# Android C2DM Auth token, one time or every time

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am outlining my plan to implement C2DM into an application and have a basic (read: stupid) question about the Auth tokens.

The client server needs to register with the google c2dm service using the white listed account:

For testing:

```
curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -d Email=theEmailYouWhitelisted -d Passwd=pass****word -d accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE -d source="your_app_name_and_ver_for_logging_purposes_only" -d service=ac2dm
```

My question is, does this happen once per application per c2dm account - ie: get the one server generated auth code using your whitelisted account, store it, then every time a message gets sent retrieve it and use:

```
curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=**authFromRegistrationAbove**" "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send" -d registration_id=**phoneRegistrationId(reciever)** -d "data.message=StringToPass" -d collapse_key=something -k
```

Or do you have to request a new Auth code for every message being pushed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Store the auth token for future pushes. From the Google [C2DM page](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html):

> Able to store the ClientLogin Auth
>   token and client registration IDs. The
>   ClientLogin Auth token is included in
>   the header of POST requests that send
>   messages. For more discussion of this
>   topic, see [ClientLogin for Installed
>   Applications.](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html) The server should store
>   the token and have a policy to refresh
>   it periodically.

Also note that Google will periodically refresh the token in an `Update-Client-Auth` header. See [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/00b03b6a0985059f/14b69680f3b6926b) on the `android-c2dm` group for details.

From my experience, I can't tell when or why Google chooses to refresh the token. It's happened to me as frequently as every day, and sometimes it's every week.

Comment: Do previous authTokens continue to function? Seems like this is the case for me..

Comment: In my experience, the old auth tokens continue to function. It's not documented for how long, or for how many messages though.